# No error is thrown but INSERT statement is not working (php,mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, angular

After executing INSERT statement there is no single error thrown and my database table is empty ,someone help please!

Service file for calling INSERT statement

roomservice.php

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');  

   if(isset($_POST['hotelName']) && isset($_POST['hasTV']) && 
                            isset($_POST['beds']) && isset($_POST['price'])){

    $roomName = $_POST['hotelName'];
    $hasTV = $_POST['hasTV'];
    $beds = $_POST['beds'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
     echo addRoom($roomName,$hasTV,$beds,$price);

    }

    function addRoom($hotelName, $hasTV, $beds , $price){
        global $conn;
        $rarray = array();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO rooms (hotelname, hastv, beds, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $hotelName, $hasTV, $beds , $price);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $rarray['sucess'] = "okej";
        }else{
            $rarray['error'] = "Database connection error";
        }
        return json_encode($rarray);
    }


    ?>
```

Angular component file where i call the service file with data passed through form.

addroom.component.ts

```
public addRoom() {
    const body = new HttpParams()
    .set('hotelname', this.roomForm.value.hotelName)
    .set('hastv', this.roomForm.value.hasTV)
    .set('beds', this.roomForm.value.beds)
    .set('price', this.roomForm.value.price);
    console.log(body.toString());
    this._api.post('roomservice.php', body.toString()).subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
      // localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.parse(data['_body']).token);
      this._router.navigate(['./']);
    }, (error) => {
      const obj = JSON.parse(error['_body']).error;
      const element  = <HTMLElement> document.getElementsByClassName('alert')[0];
      element.style.display = 'block';
      element.innerHTML = obj.split('\\r\\n').join('<br/>').split('\"').join('');
    });
  }

}
```

rooms table
[image]

client response
[image]

Comment: You haven't got error-reporting enabled, otherwise you would get an error here `$stmt->bind_param("sss", $hotelName, $hasTV, $beds , $price);`. Missing a typestring there.

Comment: Bind_param - you have 3x`s`, but 4 parameters... Also, not sure about passing all those parameters as string. You really should add error handling to your code.

Comment: You should check to see if MySQL is returning any errors

Comment: still doesn't work , tryed everything...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're trying to pass 4 arguments to the bind function but you have entered only 3 parameters. That's why its not working.

The solution is to change these two lines:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO rooms (hotelname, hastv, beds, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $hotelName, $hasTV, $beds , $price);
```

to:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `rooms` (`hotelname`, `hastv`, `beds`, `price`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $hotelName, $hasTV, $beds , $price);
```

Comment: That's a typo and should be closed as such, not answered.

Comment: Still not getting inserted row in db after i changed that.

Comment: I wonder why this answer is downvoted. It has an explanation, a solution, and solved the problem.

Comment: @PetarPetrovic if this answer did not solve your problem, then why did you accept it as a solution?

Comment: @PetarPetrovic Are you sure that the `id` column is Auto Increment Primary Key?